# What is the point of bundle package?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I understand what Rail's `bundle package` does and how to use it, but I'm drawing a blank as to *why* it would be a useful command. What utility does it have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use it when you have a need to not connect to the gem source, its useful if your moving files across machines and don't want to fetch gems from a remote source all the time. See the documentation [here](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-package.1.html).

Answer (score 6):

`bundle package` will copy all the gems required by your application into the vendor/cache folder. This also includes dependencies required by the gems.

This helps because at the time of deployment you can just run `bundle install --local` to avoid dependency on the gems repository (rubygems.org) and install all the gems from the cached folder

Because each gem might have different dependencies depending upon the platform in which it is installed, it's recommended to use `bundle package` only when your development and deployment environments are alike.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to want to avoid dependency on the gems repo?

Comment: when you are deploying your app multiple times to different environments and you have frozen your gem versions, this might be helpful. Can't think of a better usecase :)

Comment: Does this still hold true in Rails 4?